# how to Intercept SMS Messages in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, jailbreak

how to Intercept SMS Messages in iOS 6? 
before ios 6.o, I hook SMSCTServer - (void)_ingestIncomingCTMessage:(id)message to do the work, but iOS 6 abandon the class. Do you have some other ideas?

Comment: When you say "intercept", do you mean get notified when it comes in, and read the contents?  Or do you mean "block" the incoming message, so your code gets it, but the **Messages** app never does?

Comment: Thank for you reply! Actually, I mean  "block" here!

Comment: Do you find any thing to Block those SMS, if Yes then please share it thanks in advance